# Very Large Extjs App:Too Slow To Load

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd

I am creating an Extjs App by Sencha CMD for which Production  App.js size comes around 20 MB.
 Because of that, it is too slow for first time Load(Around 6-7 s Locally and 30-40s on Cloud).

1. In there any way I can hanlde this so that my App.js size Comes down?
2. Can I divide my app into Modules so that I can load only necessary files on first load and load other files on demand?

Comment: @Tejas Umm okay..But I am not sure if that will help in improving my startup load time as both both files have to load anyways for application to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ExtJS 6.5 they've introduced dynamic package loading.
Basically, you just wrap hunks of your code in Sencha Cmd packages, and then load them on the fly. Here are some links to get you started:

https://sencha.guru/2017/04/12/package-loading/

https://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-ext-js-6-5-and-sencha-cmd-6-5-ga/